# how to import something in a linear layout and place it on a canvas

Tags: android, canvas

i have a seekbar which i implemented in an xml file. i wanted to place this seekbar on a custom drawable rectangle which i have drawn using the canvas draw method and i have named the the class as "controlButtons.java", i.e different rectangles will act as menus as if.

my main problem is how should i make the seekbar appear on the rectangle without having to make the class "extend linearlayout".

is there a way to import something as a linearlayout and place it on the canvas

hope you'll be able to help me..thanks

raaj

Comment: Could we view the code for controlButtons.java

Answer (score 0):

Hope this help:

```
Bitmap bitmap = Bitmap.createBitmap(seekBarView.getMeasuredWidth(),  
                            seekBarView.getMeasuredHeight() ,Bitmap.Config.ARGB_8888); 
Canvas barCanvas = new Canvas(bitmap); 

seekBarView.draw(canvas); 
baseCanvas.drawBitmap(bitmap, x, y, null);
```

Answer (score 0):

What I would do is create a bitmap from the canvas that contains the "custom drawable rectangle" using canvas.setBitmap(bitmap);.  Then I would use TableLayout in XML to place the bitmap (using imageView) behind the seekbar.  The gives you the ability to control the seekbar and get data from it without having to redraw the canvas again completly.